# Enabling ehcache in Play 2.2.x

Tags: caching, playframework, ehcache, playframework-2.2

I'm new to play (v2.2.0), and I'm modifying the hello-play-java template. I'd like to add caching, however, the [JavaCache documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaCache) makes what appears to be conflicting statements:

> The default implementation of the cache API uses EHCache and it’s enabled by default.

and

> The cache API is provided by the play.cache.Cache object. This requires a cache plugin to be registered.

Indeed, when I import `Cache`, the compiler barfs; and older documentation that discusses plugins seems outdated as `play install ...` is no longer valid.

Thus: how can I enable the default caching module?

Comment: Not contradictory, the Cache object is a wrapper around EhCache

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Play 2.2 Migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22):

> Play cache is now split out into its own module. If you are using the
>   Play cache, you will need to add this as a dependency. For example, in
>   Build.scala:

```
val addDependencies = Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ...
)
```